# Auto checkbox form filling

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, html, microsoft-access, web-application

I have a data set like this:

```
40.45.68.70
50.51.74.90
46.49.25.30
77.78.45.12
5.78.90.94
.
.
.
goes on...
```

I would like to insert these values into a checkbox form code automatically.
The form code is like this:

```
 <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
             <label>                
                    <input type="checkbox" name="SelectAll" class="all" />All</label>
                    <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name=" " class="selector" /> </label>
                    <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name=" " class="selector" /> </label>
                    <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name=" " class="selector" /> </label>
                    <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name=" " class="selector" /> </label>

            </form> 


 <form id="form1" name="form2" method="post" action="">
             <label>                
                    <input type="checkbox" name="SelectAll" class="all" />All</label>
                    <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name=" " class="selector" /> </label>
                    <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name=" " class="selector" /> </label>
                    <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name=" " class="selector" /> </label>
                    <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name=" " class="selector" /> </label>

            </form> 


 <form id="form1" name="form3" method="post" action="">
             <label>                
                    <input type="checkbox" name="SelectAll" class="all" />All</label>
                    <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name=" " class="selector" /> </label>
                    <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name=" " class="selector" /> </label>
                    <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name=" " class="selector" /> </label>
                    <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name=" " class="selector" /> </label>

                </form>
.
.
.
goes on...
```

The output should look like this:(for the first row as an example)

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
                 <label>                
                        <input type="checkbox" name="SelectAll" class="all" />All</label>
                        <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="40" class="selector" />40 </label>
                        <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="45 " class="selector" />45 </label>
                        <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="68 " class="selector" /> 68</label>
                        <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="70 " class="selector" />70</label>

                </form>
```

I need to insert data set into the checkbox form code into the corresponding spaces. I do this manually. but there are so many of them. Is there some kind of software or code that can do this kind of work at ease?

I am not sure in which category to ask this question exactly, so if you can direct me in the right direction, that would be helpful too. thanks. 
Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: How do you want the output to look? Have an IP address in the name and the text? <input type="checkbox" name="40.45.68.70" class="selector" />40.45.68.70 </label>... etc?

Comment: I updated my post, and inserted an exemplary output. Basically, 4 values in each data row is to be inserted into a checkbox form. Unfortunately, I don't have an IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some tips for using excel to write HTML code with a formula:

1) using two double quotation "" The first acts like an escape so the second one will be part of your output

2) & is used to concatenate stuff together

3) mid() & find() functions can be used to parse your original string into smaller chunks to feed into the formula

4) use separate cells to do parts of your html, then concatenate them together

5) use copy/paste special/values when you have the code you want and want to move that to an actual page.

Hopefully this starts you in the right direction.

Comment: I am not sure if this would be an easy method, to piece together all the codes, and copy paste to another file.

Comment: I tried this now as you suggested. I come across two issues. The code looks very messy when I copy & paste it to text editor, and "" marks double in the text editor. Here is a link to see the result. https://1drv.ms/x/s!AoGkZUHlKui9gQjcl2I8Z_jnTskg

Comment: I can eliminate double quotations in text editor, can you suggest me a way to make the code organized? please.

Comment: Ok, I found a way to clean the quotations here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41320227

Comment: This method works in excel. Thanks @gns100 If there is any other suggestion to achieve this, I would be very interested to know.

Comment: Glad you found my tips somewhat useful. Sorry I don't have good  ideas about making the code look organized (with excel). I use this technique when I have a lot of repeating code with different variables embedded and I don't want to fire up my knowledge of javascript or some server side script to write the HTML code for me. I normally don't care about how the code looks, just how the results look and work. Later if I need to make changes I go back to the excel spreadsheet, not the HTML code, so I really see no reason to be able to have organized HTML code.

Comment: thanks for the tips. I also realized that most html editors organize html code with a click. it is very useful.